# Get percentiles of data-set with group by month

Tags: sql, t-sql, statistics

I have a SQL table with a whole load of records that look like this:

```
| Date       | Score |
+ -----------+-------+
| 01/01/2010 |     4 |
| 02/01/2010 |     6 |
| 03/01/2010 |    10 |
  ...
| 16/03/2010 |     2 |
```

I'm plotting this on a chart, so I get a nice line across the graph indicating score-over-time.  Lovely.

Now, what I need to do is include the average score on the chart, so we can see how that changes over time, so I can simply add this to the mix:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(SCOREDATE) 'Year', MONTH(SCOREDATE) 'Month',
    MIN(SCORE) MinScore, 
    AVG(SCORE) AverageScore, 
    MAX(SCORE) MaxScore
FROM SCORES
GROUP BY YEAR(SCOREDATE), MONTH(SCOREDATE) 
ORDER BY YEAR(SCOREDATE), MONTH(SCOREDATE)
```

That's no problem so far.

The problem is, how can I easily calculate the percentiles at each time-period?  I'm not sure that's the correct phrase.  What I need in total is:

- A line on the chart for the score (easy)
- A line on the chart for the average (easy)
- A line on the chart showing the band that 95% of the scores occupy (stumped)

It's the third one that I don't get.  I need to calculate the 5% percentile figures, which I can do singly:

```
SELECT MAX(SubQ.SCORE) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 45 PERCENT SCORE 
    FROM SCORES
    WHERE YEAR(SCOREDATE) = 2010 AND MONTH(SCOREDATE) = 1
    ORDER BY SCORE ASC) AS SubQ

SELECT MIN(SubQ.SCORE) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 45 PERCENT SCORE 
    FROM SCORES
    WHERE YEAR(SCOREDATE) = 2010 AND MONTH(SCOREDATE) = 1
    ORDER BY SCORE DESC) AS SubQ
```

But I can't work out how to get a table of all the months.

```
| Date       | Average | 45% | 55% |
+ -----------+---------+-----+-----+
| 01/01/2010 |      13 |  11 |  15 |
| 02/01/2010 |      10 |   8 |  12 |
| 03/01/2010 |       5 |   4 |  10 |
  ...
| 16/03/2010 |       7 |   7 |   9 |
```

At the moment I'm going to have to load this lot up into my app, and calculate the figures myself.  Or run a larger number of individual queries and collate the results.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? You might like to look at the docs for the `NTILE` function if it's available.

Comment: Heh, I was going to add this after I saw another question here then forgot!  I'm on 2000, so can't use NTILE :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew. This was a real brain teaser. First, my table schema for testing was:

```
Create Table Scores 
( 
    Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , [Date] datetime not null
    , Score int not null
)
```

Now, first, I calculated the values using a CTE in SQL 2008 in order to check my answers and then I built a solution that should work in SQL 2000. So, in SQL 2008 we do something like:

```
;With 
    SummaryStatistics As
    (
        Select Year([Date]) As YearNum
            , Month([Date]) As MonthNum
            , Min(Score) As MinScore
            , Max(Score) As MaxScore
            , Avg(Score) As AvgScore
        From Scores
        Group By Month([Date]), Year([Date])
    )
    , Percentiles As
    (
        Select Year([Date]) As YearNum
            , Month([Date]) As MonthNum
            , Score
            , NTile( 100 ) Over ( Partition By Month([Date]), Year([Date]) Order By Score ) As Percentile
        From Scores
    )
    , ReportedPercentiles As
    (
        Select YearNum, MonthNum
            , Min(Case When Percentile = 45 Then Score End) As Percentile45
            , Min(Case When Percentile = 55 Then Score End) As Percentile55
        From Percentiles
        Where Percentile In(45,55)
        Group By YearNum, MonthNum
    )
Select SS.YearNum, SS.MonthNum
    , SS.MinScore, SS.MaxScore, SS.AvgScore
    , RP.Percentile45, RP.Percentile55
From SummaryStatistics As SS
    Join ReportedPercentiles As RP
        On  RP.YearNum = SS.YearNum
            And RP.MonthNum = SS.MonthNum
Order By SS.YearNum, SS.MonthNum
```

Now for a SQL 2000 solution. In essence, the trick is to use a couple of temporary tables to tally the occurances of the scores.

```
If object_id('tempdb..#Working') is not null
    DROP TABLE #Working
GO
Create Table #Working 
    (
    YearNum int not null
    , MonthNum int not null
    , Score int not null
    , Occurances int not null
    , Constraint PK_#Working Primary Key Clustered ( MonthNum, YearNum, Score )
    )
GO
Insert #Working(MonthNum, YearNum, Score, Occurances)
Select Month([Date]), Year([Date]), Score, Count(*)
From Scores
Group By Month([Date]), Year([Date]), Score
GO
If object_id('tempdb..#SummaryStatistics') is not null
    DROP TABLE #SummaryStatistics
GO
Create Table #SummaryStatistics
    (
    MonthNum int not null
    , YearNum int not null
    , Score int not null
    , Occurances int not null
    , CumulativeTotal int not null
    , Percentile float null
    , Constraint PK_#SummaryStatistics Primary Key Clustered ( MonthNum, YearNum, Score )
    )
GO
Insert #SummaryStatistics(YearNum, MonthNum, Score, Occurances, CumulativeTotal)
Select W2.YearNum, W2.MonthNum, W2.Score, W2.Occurances, Sum(W1.Occurances)-W2.Occurances
From #Working As W1
    Join #Working As W2 
        On W2.YearNum = W1.YearNum
            And W2.MonthNum = W1.MonthNum
Where W1.Score <= W2.Score
Group By W2.YearNum, W2.MonthNum, W2.Score, W2.Occurances

Update #SummaryStatistics
Set Percentile = SS.CumulativeTotal * 100.0 / MonthTotal.Total
From #SummaryStatistics As SS
    Join    (
            Select SS1.YearNum, SS1.MonthNum, Max(SS1.CumulativeTotal) As Total
            From #SummaryStatistics As SS1
            Group By SS1.YearNum, SS1.MonthNum
            ) As MonthTotal
        On MonthTotal.YearNum = SS.YearNum
            And MonthTotal.MonthNum = SS.MonthNum

Select GeneralStats.*, Percentiles.Percentile45, Percentiles.Percentile55
From    (
        Select  Year(S1.[Date]) As YearNum
            , Month(S1.[Date]) As MonthNum
            , Min(S1.Score) As MinScore
            , Max(S1.Score) As MaxScore
            , Avg(S1.Score) As AvgScore
        From Scores As S1
        Group By Month(S1.[Date]), Year(S1.[Date])
        ) As GeneralStats
    Join    (
            Select SS1.YearNum, SS1.MonthNum
                , Min(Case When SS1.Percentile >= 45 Then Score End) As Percentile45
                , Min(Case When SS1.Percentile >= 55 Then Score End) As Percentile55
            From #SummaryStatistics As SS1
            Group By SS1.YearNum, SS1.MonthNum 
            ) As Percentiles
        On Percentiles.YearNum = GeneralStats.YearNum
            And Percentiles.MonthNum = GeneralStats.MonthNum
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a set of operations :)
Seems to work though, so that's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without the data, I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but maybe this will help get you there with two queries per year instead of 24...

```
SELECT MAX(SubQ.SCORE), MyMonth  FROM
    (SELECT TOP 45 PERCENT SCORE , MONTH(SCOREDATE) as MyMonth 
    FROM SCORES
    WHERE YEAR(SCOREDATE) = 2010
    ORDER BY SCORE ASC) AS SubQ
group by  MyMonth
```