# get top and bottom 25th percentile average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with list of employees and the number of units that they have sold.

I want to get the top 25 percentile Avg units sold and Bottom 25 percentile Avg units sold.

I have created a representation of my data [SLQ Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a2c)

I really have no idea how to start on this? All the examples i see are for SQL Server and not MySQL. Here is what i am thinking.

I want 25 percentile and cant limit to 25 items. Basically it would involve:

```
1) #_of_employees = The number of total employees. 

2) #_of_employees_in_25_percentile =  #_of_employees*0.25 

3) Calculate the sum of the units sold by the top/bottom 25 percentile (limit #_of_employees_in_25_percentile)

4) Divide the sum by #_of_employees_in_25_percentile to get the average.
```

How can all this be done efficiently in MySQL?

Comment: what sql server example you've found so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588360/how-to-get-percentile-instead-of-rank OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403326/get-percentiles-of-data-set-with-group-by-month

Comment: I see. I am afraid mysql does not have support for this (sql server would probably use NTILE)

Comment: @codeNinja add your desired result set with some more sample data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution that uses a devious trick I learned [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function/3333697#3333697).

```
SELECT id, unit_sold, n * 100 / @total AS percentile
FROM (
  SELECT id, unit_sold, @total := @total + unit_sold AS n
  FROM mydata, (SELECT @total := 0) AS total
  ORDER BY unit_sold ASC
) AS t
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a2c/15/0)

Comment: Nice solution! Just one minor point, I think it should be `@total := @total + 1` instead of `@total := @total + unit_sold`, it appears that the percentile is computed on the employee number, rather than the total unit sold.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT
  SUM(unit_sold) AS sum_tot, SUM(unit_sold)/count(id) AS average,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile<25 THEN unit_sold ELSE 0 END) AS sum_top25,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile<25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_top25,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile<25 THEN unit_sold ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN percentile<25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS average_top25,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile>75 THEN unit_sold ELSE 0 END) AS sum_bottom25,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile>75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_bottom25,
  SUM(CASE WHEN percentile>75 THEN unit_sold ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN percentile>75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS average_bottom25
FROM
(SELECT
  id, unit_sold, c * 100 / @counter AS percentile
FROM
   (SELECT
      m.*, @counter:=@counter+1 AS c 
   FROM
     (SELECT @counter:=0) AS initvar, mydata AS m
   ORDER BY unit_sold desc
   ) AS t
WHERE
  c <= (25/100 * @counter)
  OR c >= (75/100 * @counter)
) AS t2
```

Output:

```
SUM_TOT AVERAGE     SUM_TOP25   COUNT_TOP25 AVERAGE_TOP25 SUM_BOTTOM25  COUNT_BOTTOM25  AVERAGE_BOTTOM25
850     283.3333    500         1            500          350           2               175
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a2c/69).

The idea is to use the [MySQL: LIMIT by a percentage of the amount of records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records) solution to get the percentiles. Based on that (and on [pdw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25316323/1983854)) we create an output in which we just show the top 25% and bottom 75%.

Finally, we count and sum to get the values you requested.

---

Note this runs on top of the command:

```
SELECT
  id, unit_sold, c * 100 / @counter AS percentile
FROM
   (SELECT
      m.*, @counter:=@counter+1 AS c 
   FROM
     (SELECT @counter:=0) AS initvar, mydata AS m
   ORDER BY unit_sold desc
   ) AS t
WHERE
  c <= (25/100 * @counter)
  OR c >= (75/100 * @counter)
```

Whose output is:

```
ID  UNIT_SOLD   PERCENTILE
d   500         20
a   250         80
e   100         100
```

Answer (score -1):

How about going with this logic:

- Select all, order by percentile (DESC), limit to 25
- Select all, order by percentile (ASC), limit to 25

Is this the  type of logic you're looking for ?

Sample queries:

```
$q1 = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY percentile DESC LIMIT 25)
$q2 = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY percentile ASC LIMIT 25)
```

Comment: Sorry, replace percentile by unit_sold. This should allow you to view the quantity of units sold. From there, calculate the percentile.

Comment: Limit cannot be 25. I need 25 percentile. Not 25. See updated question.

Comment: Ok, after reading the changes, may I suggest you look at this question and the confirmed solution ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065855/select-nth-percentile-from-mysql

Comment: @DaveWoodhall that answer is somewhat similar but not what i need. I need the Average Units sold by the Top or Bottom 25% of employees. The answer your pointed to give the `Row` that is closest to `X` percentile.