# mySQL: Finding average after removing top and bottom nth% of data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns: list_num, sales_price, and days_on_market

I want to run one query that will output a single number for the average of column 'days_on_market' with the top 5% and bottom 5% of rows removed when ordered by 'sales_price'.

I have found an example that I think would help here but the answer is too complicated for me to understand (I just started learning mySQL last week). See this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249833/get-top-and-bottom-25th-percentile-average).

Here is my code:

```
SELECT round(avg(days_on_market),0) as "90% Sell In"
FROM sold_q3_2016
WHERE list_num NOT IN (
    SELECT list_num FROM sold_q3_2016 ORDER BY sales_price LIMIT (count(list_num)*0.05)
    ) OR list_num NOT IN (
    SELECT list_num FROM sold_q3_2016 ORDER BY sales_price desc LIMIT (count(list_num)*0.05)
    )
;
```

Now I can't even run this as I get the syntax error around the count function inside of the LIMIT clause but I wanted to leave it here to show my thought process. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
SELECT AVG(days_on_market) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    l.*
    , @rownumber := @rownumber + 1 AS rownumber
    FROM list_num l
    , (SELECT @rownumber := 0) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY sales_price DESC
) subquery_alias
WHERE rownumber >= @rownumber * 0.05
AND rownumber <= @rownumber * 0.95
```

- more information on [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Nice, I was working on a different approach using `LIMIT` but that seems not to accept the use of variables ... which meant converting to prepared statements (due to an apparent bug see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql).